# how to detect "other software that intercepts the connection and act like a man-in-the-middle"

Tags: security

I checked ubuntu proxy settings, nothing set.
Checked also VPN, nothing set.

If I try to click on a video on a google link that opens youtube, using firefox, I get this message:

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to www.youtube.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
```

(there is no problem if I open the link in a new tab)

I got the man-in-the-middle tip from:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1267074

I think there is no hack attack... but I got curious if there could have some way to determine this man-in-the-middle other than proxy or VPN settings. May be checking all the in between connections/hosts that happen from my machine to youtube? I forgot the command that does that, not sure if useful tho.

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: Guess: the data you are trying to retrieve via https from the youtube server(s) uses a certificate that cannot be verified with your currently installed root certificates. Update your certificates; if that doesn't help, use e.g. the developer extension to check which certificate firefox sees. If the certificate looks fishy (compare with the certificate you get when connected to the internet from another location), then someone (possibly your ISP) thinks he needs to intercept https requests.

Comment: I think the command you forgot is `traceroute` - although it has limited application in this case

Comment: [Start Firefox in safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/diagnose-firefox-issues-using-troubleshoot-mode?redirectslug=troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode&redirectlocale=en-US) and try again. Does it work?

Comment: Install `tracepath`, it is a TCP `traceroute`, lets one specify the TCP Port to trace. Better for detecting MITM